# Making sense of complex conjunctions

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

1. When a connector is added to a coordinating conjunction, what is the combined entity called? An emphatic conjunction? Example:

> He is young and therefore strong. ("and therefore")

2. Similarly, when an adverb precedes a subordinating conjunction, what will the combined entity be called? Example:

> He arrived immediately after we left. ("immediately after")

Thanks

Comment: Please make your punctuation better. I cannot really understand your question. And what do you mean by complex conjunctions?

Answer (score 1):

> *He is young* [*and therefore strong*].

There's no special name for the combination of "and" and "therefore". "And" is a coordinator (your conjunction) and "therefore" is a connective adverb. They work in combination, though it's just "and" that marks the coordination: "therefore" is thus a modifier within the second coordinate.

> *He arrived* [*immediately after we left*].

Here, "immediately" is an adverbial modifier in the bracketed preposition phrase.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your reply. My query is that if "therefore "is a modifier within the second coordinate which has only an adjective (strong) as its part. So,  is it that the connective adverb here modifies the adjective.

Comment: @Sanjay Not quite. The second coordinate is the adjective phrase "and therefore strong", where "and" is a coordinator, "therefore" a modifier and "strong" an adjective.

Comment: And the second part is an elided version of "he is strong": "He is young and therefore he is strong." Here you have an adverb modifying "he is strong", and it doesn't change when you elide "he is".

Comment: It's a distributive coordination construction with "he" as subject, and a coordination of two AdjPs as predicative complement. He is [young] and [therefore strong]. I think this is much better than saying we have a coordination of AdjPs with ellipsis within the second coordinate.